# Lua require mpack twice in different files fails

Tags: lua

Given the following (fully complete) Lua file:

```lua
-- test/file1_spec.lua
local mpack = require('mpack')
print(mpack)
```

It works without a problem if I execute the file with [busted](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/): `busted test`.

And if I update the file to load `mpack` twice:

```lua
-- test/file1_spec.lua
local mpack = require('mpack')
print(mpack)
local mpack2 = require('mpack')
print(mpack2)
```

It still works. But if I add a second file (additionally to the one above) with:

```lua
-- test/file2_spec.lua
local mpack = require('mpack')
print(mpack)
```

Then loading `mpack` on this second file fails with the following error:

```
test/file2_spec.lua:1: attempt to index a mpack.NIL value
```

How does require work? How can I require `mpack` in different Lua files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with `mpack` module itself, it cannot be loaded twice for some reason:

```
-- demo.lua
require('mpack')
-- remove the loaded package from a cache, otherwise the package will not be reloaded
package.loaded['mpack'] = nil
require('mpack')
```

```
$ lua demo.lua
lua: attempt to index a mpack.NIL value
```

It also happens with `busted` because `busted` flushes the package cache between tests:

> Test environment insulation saves the global table `_G` and any currently loaded packages `package.loaded`, restoring them to their original state at the completion of the `insulate` block.
>
> By default each test file runs in a separate `insulate` block, which can be disabled with the `--no-auto-insulate` flag.

So, you have several options:

1. Use `busted --no-auto-insulate` flag. I wouldn't recommend doing that because it disables isolation at all.
2. Use `busted -e 'require("mpack")'`. An expression passed with `-e` argument is executed before any tests, so an insulation mechanism will not remove an already cached package.
3. Use `expose` block:

   ```
   -- spec/__init_spec.lua
   -- The name of this file is started with underscores to ensure that it will be processed
   -- before any other spec file. I don't know how to do it in a proper way (if it's possible).
   expose('preload mpack module', function()
       require('mpack')
   end)
   ```

See https://olivinelabs.com/busted/#defining-tests, “Describe: Insulate & Expose blocks” section for details.

I'll check `mpack` source code later and maybe I can fix this issue.

UPD: A qoute from Lua reference manual about `package.loaded`:

> A table used by `require` to control which modules are already loaded. When you require a module modname and `package.loaded[modname]` is not false, `require` simply returns the value stored there.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.loaded

Comment: Thanks for the information. Very helpful and thanks for confirming that I wasn't doing anything wrong. I've been looking at `libmpack-lua` now and [this is the offending line](https://github.com/libmpack/libmpack-lua/blob/master/lmpack.c#L1157). That's the line that throws the error when loading it a second time. I still don't know why though.

Comment: Using [this snippet](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html) to print the Lua stack, the stack right before the [offending line](https://github.com/libmpack/libmpack-lua/blob/master/lmpack.c#L1157) the first time is "table table table table function" and the second time, at the exact same place, it's "table table table userdata function". I'm not sure why the stack looks different the for the second require.

Comment: Also, it looks like [removing this line](https://github.com/libmpack/libmpack-lua/blob/master/lmpack.c#L1164) allows the double require. Can it be that somehow `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` doesn't get cleaned up when unloading a package and, when trying to require the second time, the NIL userdata gets added to the stack instead of the new metatable as it should?

Comment: It looks like `lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, NIL_NAME);` returns `nil` on the first require but `userdata` on the second require. I don't know how can that mess up with the second require though.

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/libmpack/libmpack-lua/blob/master/lmpack.c#L1154) inserts a table on the first require and userdata on the second require.

Comment: Would it make sense to, at the beginning of the `luaopen_mpack` function, check if `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` already has the `NIL_NAME` key and unset it, to clean global resources before continuing? Or, is there a way to reset the `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` from Lua between busted tests?

Comment: I guess I'll submit a PR to the repo with a proposal to clean up `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX`. In the meantime, the expose block with a proper comment explaining the issue looks like the best solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the metatable used for the `NIL` userdata is created using `luaL_newmetatable` that first checks if a value with the same name already exists in the registry and returns it if it does, so when the library is loaded again, it returns the existing userdata instead of a newly created table. I've created a pull request: https://github.com/libmpack/libmpack-lua/pull/22